# self directive does not get executed in angular modal

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, directive

I’m using the Angular UI Bootstrap modal to display a self form directive, but this directive is not rendered.

In the self directive, I write a piece of fake html codes which only displays an input element. 
It can be displayed in main page as expected, but it disappeared in the modal dialog.
Can anyone help on this? Why the directive in modal dialog does not display?

The code is in plunker below:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Qcy7eSf4abJ706VOSN5n?p=preview

The code snippet is also as below:

```js
var app = angular.module('modalExample', ['ui.bootstrap']);
    app.directive('formView', [
        "$compile",
        "$timeout",
        function($compile, $timeout){
            return {
                restrict: "E",
                replace: true,
                transclusion: true,
                scope: {
                    config: "="
                },
                compile: function(element, attrs, transclude) {
                    return {
                        pre: function ($scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                            var fakeHtml = '<input type="text" ng-model="test"/>';
                            angular.element(element).append($compile(fakeHtml)($scope));
                        }
                    };
                }
            };
        }
    ])
    app.controller('modalController', ['$scope', '$uibModal', function($scope, $uibModal) {
        $scope.open = function() {
            var modalinstance = $uibModal.open({
                scope: $scope,
                templateUrl: 'modal.html'
            })
        };
    }]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="modalExample">
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="modalController">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="modal.html">
    aaa <form-view></form-view>
  </script>
  
    <form-view></form-view>
    <button type="button" ng-click="open()">Open Dialog</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your directive like below-

```
app.directive('formView', [
        "$compile",
        "$timeout",
        function($compile, $timeout){
            return {
                restrict: "E",
                replace: true,
                transclusion: true,
                scope: {
                    config: "="
                },
               link: function ($scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                  var fakeHtml = '<input type="text" ng-model="test"/>';
                         angular.element(iElement).append($compile(fakeHtml)($scope));
                        }


            };
        }
    ]);
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: it works, as I am new in angular, could you kindly share some comments on it? why does link function work?